# Locus of complete curves on $\mathcal M_g$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Is the union of the complete curves on $\mathcal M_g$ Zariski dense? ($g \gg 0$)

I know it is hard to find higher-dimensional complete subvarieties of $\mathcal M_g$, but a quasiprojective variety can have lots of complete curves but nothing higher dimensional, e.g. the complement of a codimension 2 linear subspace of $\mathbb P^n$.  I am curious whether the known complete curves can deform in $\mathcal M_g$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the complement of a do dimension 2 linear subspace in $\mathbb{P}^n$ ?

Comment: @Ottem might know the answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $M_g^S$ be the Satake compactification of $M_g$. It is a singular projective variety. For $g \geq 3$, the codimension of $M_g^S \setminus M_g$ is $\geq 2$. If $p \in M_g$ is a point, then a sufficiently general linear subspace through $p$ cuts out a complete curve not meeting the Satake boundary. Conclusion: through any point of $M_g$, $g \geq 3$, passes a complete curve.

Answer (score 0):

The Kodaira-Parshin construction produces, for every integer $r \ge 2$, an integer $g$ such that every curve of genus $r$ embeds in ${\cal M}_g$. I think the construction is such that when you deform one of these embeddings, you get another one, i.e. ${\cal M}_{r,1}$ is being embedded in ${\cal M}_g$. But I guess the image is not Zariski dense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I believe that Steven Diaz wrote a number of papers bounding the dimensions of complete subvarieties of $\mathcal{M}_g$. That would certainly bound what you could do with complete families of curves.